# Which one is correct: "take care of payment for something" or "take care of the payment for something?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Can you please tell me if I need to use *the* before *payment* in the context below?

> I'd like to know if you are going to be the one taking care of
> (**the**) payment for our services.

Is the use of *the* optional there, if so, which one is more common?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about one specific payment for your services, you would use the definite article 'the'. We use a definite article when we are talking about  one single specific thing.

*I'd like to know if you are going to be the one taking care of the payment for our services which is due by the end of this month.*

If you are talking about the whole matter of payment more generally, perhaps over a period of time, and involving more than one transfer of funds, you could omit the definite article.

*I'd like to know if you are going to be the one taking care of payment for our services during the period of the five-year contract which has now been signed.*

[What are definite and indefinite articles?](https://www.theschoolrun.com/what-are-definite-and-indefinite-articles)